# vhdl error code 10500 for keywords already present

Tags: vhdl

This code is for a PRBS (pseudo-random binary sequence) receiver. it is supposed to take three values and simulate a PRBS generator and check the obtained vales with the values generated.
But the code is showing errors for keywords like begin which are already present

```
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee. std_logic_arith.all;
    use ieee. std_logic_unsigned.all;

    entity receiver is
    port(
        inp : in std_logic;
        clock : in std_logic;
        count : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
        check : out std_logic);
    end receiver;

    architecture rec of receiver is
    signal P : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    signal O : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);

    process (clock)
        variable cnt  : integer range 0 to 3;
        begin
            if clock'event and clock='1'  then
                P <= inp & P(2 downto 1);
                cnt<=cnt+1;
            end if;
            if (cnt = 3) then
                O<=P;
                elseif (cnt >3)
                O <= inp & O(2 downto 1);
            end if;
            if((O(2) xor O(0)) = P(0))  
                check <= '0';
            else
                check <= '1';
                count <= count +1;
            end if;
        end process;
    end rec;
```

> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at receiver.vhd(18) near text "process";  expecting "begin", or a declaration statement
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at receiver.vhd(21) near text "if";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("if" is a reserved keyword), or a concurrent statement
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at receiver.vhd(21) near text "and";  expecting "(", or "'", or "."
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at receiver.vhd(24) near text "if";  expecting ";", or an identifier ("if" is a reserved keyword), or "architecture"
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at receiver.vhd(25) near text "then";  expecting "<="
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at receiver.vhd(28) near text "O";  expecting "(", or "'", or "."
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at receiver.vhd(29) near text "if";  expecting ";", or an identifier ("if" is a reserved keyword), or "architecture"
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at receiver.vhd(31) near text "check";  expecting "<="
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at receiver.vhd(32) near text "else";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("else" is a reserved keyword), or a concurrent statement
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at receiver.vhd(35) near text "if";  expecting ";", or an identifier ("if" is a reserved keyword), or "architecture"

Comment: Try working your way backwards, by removing code until it compiles, and then add code to understand why you break it.  If you then don't understand each of the syntax error, then you can post it a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Also, consider using ModelSim simulator for initial compile, since the turn-around time is faster than for Quartus.  Altera ModelSim Starter Edition is free.

Comment: Or look at th efirst error. Look at an example of an `architecture` and compare it with your code. See if there is a difference involving either of the keywords in the error message. Hint : there is.

Comment: A missing reserved word (`begin`) following the signal declarations, which separates architecture declarative items from concurrent statements (like a process statement).  You misspelled `elsif` as elseif, and it's missing a `then` the next if statement is missing a `then`. `cnt` is not a signal, a variable a different compould delimiter (`:=`).  (And a constrained integer doesn't do modular arithmetic). `count` is a mode out port and can't be read And you should not increment `count` based on a combinatorial enable (in the `else` from the `if`, we call that a striking oscillator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of your entity needs to look like this:

```
entity receiver is
  port (
    -- Your ports
  );
end receiver;

architecture rec of receiver is
  -- Declarations here
begin  -- ** Your code is missing this part

  process (clock)
  begin
    -- your process
  end process;

end rec;
```

As mentioned in the comments, always start with the *first* error you see; understand and solve that one first, and many later errors will normally go away as a result.

You have declared `cnt` as a variable, and then are trying to increment it using `cnt <= cnt + 1;`, but variables assignment should use `:=` not `<=`.

The next error is your use of `elseif`; this is not a real keyword, and it looks like you wanted to use `elsif`. This line is also missing a `then`.

You then have a line `if((O(2) xor O(0)) = P(0))`, which is again missing a `then`.

Lastly, you are trying to directly increment `count` which is an `out` port. This is not possible, since you are trying to read an output in order to add one to it; there are a few ways to resolve this, but personally I would create an intermediate signal (e.g. `count_s`), which you use in your process, then assign your output to this signal with `count <= count_s`, somewhere outside the process.

With all these issues resolved, your code at least compiles.

---

As a side note, it would help you to have better vertical alignment of your code; your `end process` should vertically align with its opening `process`, and so on.